# XCode Media Library Not Updating

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I'm trying to work on an iPhone app via XCode but despite the fact that the images I made for the app are in the project folder, they won't appear in the "media library" menu for images I can drag into the app. I know they're in the right folder because they're in the same folder as the default images that are available. Does anybody know how I can force xcode to recognize the images?

Comment: Could you please send us the folder tree you've got for you project?